# How can I find a replacement for my vida shower cartridges?

Tags: shower, cartridge

I have a vida rain head shower. The cartridge is leaking and the shutoff valves don’t work well either. I need to replace all 3. I can’t find any model number on anything other than 27-42-7L on the cartridge housing. I don’t know who makes this but it might be Grohe since that’s what Google sends me as top listings for vida. Any help appreciated.
[image: closeup cartridge]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you contacted Vida?

Comment: Or a local plumbing supply house. Note that if you are in a neighborhood that was all built at once, there's good odds the same valve was used in all of them, and I'd so the local hardware store may be clever enough to keep a few spare parts in stock.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to take it to a plumbing supply store. They have all the catalogs and stock numbers for parts. If they don't have it in stock, they can order it for you. Some of the home stores have a good supply of cartridges but you'd be eyeballing the parts and not the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You look like you can cheat with an Aquabrass catridge . Abca01004 should work.

Comment: You could improve your answer by adding a photo or link to it

Comment: What _looks_ like you can substitute one for the other? What do you base this statement on?